# put a non static variable into static method in java

Tags: java, oop

guys i have a static method

```
 public static void method1(){}
```

and i want to put a non static variable in it and access it by setVariable ... is it acceptable to do that ?

example

```
private String var;

public setVariable(String var){
    this.var = var;
}

public static void method1(){
    System.out.println(var):
}
```

Comment: why don't you try it yourself

Comment: Either make it static or create an instance inside the static method and set the variable on that. No other way.

Comment: *"is it acceptable to do that ?"* it is not even possible. Use `static` with care and not as default.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can, however, call setVariable (from a static context) on a static object, or on the object you get as a parameter. Both of these will work:

```
public static MyObj staticObj = new MyObj();

public static void myStaticMethod(MyObj obj) {
    obj.setVariable("newVal");
    staticObj.setVariable("newVal");
}
```